# R Subset by row numbers

Tags: r, subset

I have a large matrix “A” (14 columns but 250 000 rows). It has no id column.

I have another matrix “B” (14x1) with 14 numbers.

```
1   1   3   7   15  31  63  127 255 511 1023    2047    4095    8191
```

I would like to subset “A” taking only the rows that have a number in B. Eg. Row 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc.

I have tried the following:

```
newA <- A[nrow(A) %in% c(B),]
```

I didn’t work. I have also tried to add an id column to the large matrix A (e.g. `A$id <- 1:nrow(A)` but it didn’t work either.

Comment: `nrow(A)` will return the number of rows in A which is not what you need here. `nrow(A)` %in% `c(B)` is `TRUE` only when B contains the actual number 250000, which is not what you are trying to do. So your expression evaluates to `A[FALSE,]`; in other words, no rows from A are returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting B to a numeric vector and use that to index A - this works with matrices regardless of how many rows and columns they have.

```
B<-as.numeric(as.character(B))

newA<-A[B,]
```

Edit - refined for clarity and information on applicability to matrices of all dimensions.